# Querying a JSON object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

I am quite new to using Node.js.  I was looking for a good way to parse and query a JSON object.  I have the following JSON object loaded in as a file.

```
[
{"Key":"Accept","Values":["Application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Application/Json","Application/Xml"]},
{"Key":"Accept-Charset","Values":["UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1"]},
{"Key":"Accept-Encoding","Values":["compress", "gzip"]},
{"Key":"Accept-Language","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Accept-Ranges","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Age","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Allow","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Authorization","Values":["Bearer"]},
{"Key":"Cache-Control","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Connection","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Content-Encoding","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Content-Language","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Content-Length","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Content-Location","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Content-MD5","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Content-Range","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Content-Type","Values":["Application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Application/Json","Application/Xml"]},
{"Key":"Date","Values":[]},
{"Key":"ETag","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Expect","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Expires","Values":[]},
{"Key":"From","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Host","Values":[]},
{"Key":"If-Match","Values":[]},
{"Key":"If-Modified-Since","Values":[]},
{"Key":"If-None-Match","Values":[]},
{"Key":"If-Range","Values":[]},
{"Key":"If-Unmodified-Since","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Last-Modified","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Max-Forwards","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Pragma","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Proxy-Authenticate","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Proxy-Authorization","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Range","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Referer","Values":[]},
{"Key":"TE","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Trailer","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Transfer-Encoding","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Upgrade","Values":[]},
{"Key":"User-Agent","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Via","Values":[]},
{"Key":"Warning","Values":[]}
]
```

I want to be able to find a Key by value and return the values array.

So for example how do I find the values where the key is equal to `Content-Type`.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You should change your JSON if possible. You don't need an array with lots of objects inside it.  You just need one object with separate keys like `{"Accept-Charset": ["UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1"], 
"Accept-Encoding": ["compress", "gzip"]}`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment notwithstanding, I would loop through the array like so:

```
function searchByKey(key) {
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++){
    if (arr[i]['Key'] === key) {
      return arr[i]['Values'];
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Since you're using Node.js, you can take advantage of the newer [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var myData = require('./data.json'),
  myFilteredData = myData.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.key === 'Content-Type';
  });
```

Comment: In the case that the OP wants to access several of the keys randomly, wouldn't it better to use the Array.prototype.reduce filter to convert the array to a keyed object and find them through that object instead?